# How to remove registered app in mailchimp?

Tags: mailchimp

I registered an app in MailChimp but I changed my mind. I wonder if I can delete it?

Comment: Have you tried the [edit button next to the registered app](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/qr4TVY5tDhiXIFzgmumZ-8qjNlRyKPD2CxqZ70HkA8AWkf5NfpTOoBa34DuqRxYpjNtzfd6Bd_yyc5AuiY51weSA0-rTYEG08eJ1ciL6kPCbjUNkeIcNUmbv7W1kRrpGWOuAJ-6-)?

Comment: All the edit button allows you to do is update the information. There is no delete or remove option, not even a "disable" option even though the overview has an "enabled yes/no" column. Frustrating.